# manipulação de json via linha de comando

Tags: json, api, shell-script

Estou utilizando o `jq` para manipular `json` via linha de comando.

Tendo como entrada um json obtido via api do gitlab:

```
[
  {
    "id": 001,
    "description": "Uma descrição teste",
    "ssh_url_to_repo": "git@gitlab.teste.net:shazam/dc.git",
    "created_at": "2019-04-22T19:55:04.851Z",
    "last_activity_at": "2019-04-24T17:09:28.217Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 002,
    "description": "Uma descrição teste",
    "ssh_url_to_repo": "git@gitlab.teste.net:marvel/marvel.git",
    "created_at": "2019-04-22T19:55:04.851Z",
    "last_activity_at": "2019-04-23T17:09:28.217Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 003,
    "description": "Uma descrição teste",
    "ssh_url_to_repo": "git@gitlab.teste.net:one/piece.git",
    "created_at": "2019-04-22T19:55:04.851Z",
    "last_activity_at": "2019-04-22T17:09:28.217Z"
  }
]
```

Eu rodo o seguinte comando:

```
if .[].ssh_url_to_repo | contains("one/piece") then .[] | .last_activity_at else false end
```

E obtenho a seguinte saída:

```
false
false
"2019-04-24T17:09:28.217Z"
"2019-04-23T17:09:28.217Z"
"2019-04-22T17:09:28.217Z"
```

Eu queria a data apenas quando ele acha uma `ssh` que contém a substring `one/piece`. Porém, quando ele acha essa substring ele imprime a data de todos os objetos.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Que outra ferramenta, além do `jq` posso utilizar para manipular `json`?

Answer (score 0):

(Testar com o habitual `jq 'programa' f.json`)

Tenta algo como selecionar os que interessam:

```
.[] | select(.ssh_url_to_repo | contains("one/piece")).last_activity_at
```

Outra alternativa seria `map(select(cond).campo )`:

```
map(select(.ssh_url_to_repo | contains("one/piece")).last_activity_at)
```

Para obter os falsos como aparecem na tua versão:

```
map(if .ssh_url_to_repo | contains("one/piece") then  .last_activity_at else false end)
```